# Old Linux gui framework?

Tags: linux, user-interface

Some old Linux programs seems to use a different gui framework than GTK or QT, what is it?

Like the old Netscape for Linux:

[image: http://www.gis.usu.edu/unix/howtos/netscape6.gif]
<sub>(source: [usu.edu](http://www.gis.usu.edu/unix/howtos/netscape6.gif))</sub>

Or Project Manager (objective c ide)

[image: http://home.gna.org/pmanager/Screenshots/0.2/FileManagerModule.png]
<sub>(source: [pmanager at home.gna.org](http://home.gna.org/pmanager/Screenshots/0.2/FileManagerModule.png))</sub>

And is it possible to theme it?

Comment: Project Manager seems to be using some OpenStep implementation, probably GNUStep. IIRC, everything from Netscape 4+ (including Firefox) uses its own framework based on XML and Javascript, called XUL.

Comment: I guess this question is better for [Unix SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser SE](https://superuser.com/). Nevertheless, this theme looks rad.

Comment: Never heard of GNUstep, thanks! Think that's what I was looking for. Any other old linux gui frameworks?

Comment: As for other old toolkits, there is Xaw (X Athena Widgets), and its variants Xaw3d ans Xaw95; there is Motif (now OpenMotif) and its clone Lesstif; there is FLTK, ...

Comment: Thanks, I think that answers my question :-)